# Mysql not accepting connections from some sources

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server (v8.0) running on windows server 2016. I also have IIS running and PHPMyAdmin installed. In addition to this, I have a PHP web application which runs on the same server (under IIS) which accesses the MySQL database. Finally, I have several Python scripts which access the MySQL database.

Somehow, I have lost the ability to access the database from the Python scripts, but the web application still works and PHPMyAdmin can see and modify the database.

Even more strangely, I can no longer user MySQL Workbench to access the server from a PC on the local network, and PHPMyAdmin cannot access the users table of the mysql database. I can't change user details at all through PHPMyAdmin, I get the error:

**Error in processing request**

**Error code: 500**

**Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)**

**It seems that the connection to server has been lost.**

MySQL Workbench gives me this error:

**Your connection attempt failed for user 'user' to the MySQL server at SERVERADDRESS:PORT:**

**Access denied for user 'user'@'SERVERADDRESS' (using password: YES)**

I have checked that the server can accept connections from remote computers by adding bind-address=0.0.0.0 to the my.ini file. I have also checked to ensure that 3306 is allowed through the firewall.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: "have lost", so what changed recently?

Comment: Access denied means your `user/pass` did not work most probably. Please check them they are correct.

Comment: If you're getting an access denied error then it's not a firewall problem - you're able to connect to the server, but your login credentials are incorrect. Since you say you can "no longer" do this, then it implies something has changed. Presumably a password has changed, or the privileges granted to it. Or maybe even the user has been removed. I suggest logging into mysql from the server itself, as root, and having a look around

Comment: There must be something in your user table that is stopping you. Either the password is incorrect or the serveraddress you are connection from are not allowed for that user. We need more info to determine why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADyson and MrApnea pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was caused by my main database user having the host reset from % to localhost, I'm not sure how this happened or when. As the app was running locally, this was not affected, but all other access was denied (including MySQL workbench). My root user is set to local only for security.

To fix this, I connected to the server via RDP and logged in to the console as the root user. I then ran these commands to see the error:

```
use mysql;
select host, user from user;
```

This showed me that the main user account had "localhost" in the host. I ran this command to update this user:

```
update user set host='%' where user='username' and host='localhost'; flush privileges;
```